# How to do it right. (Annual cycle with pie chart)

Tags: javascript, highcharts, pie-chart

Good day everyone

I have tried to set up a yearly cycle with a pie chart. It worked, but I programmed dirty code and now I wonder how to do it correctly. Does anyone have any tips on how I can :

1. how can i create a frame around a whole series.
2. how can i define a period that runs through the end of the year as one range.
3. have I possibly used a completely wrong chart type, is there a better one?

```js
        $(function () {
                // Create the chart
                $('#container').highcharts({
                    chart: {
                        type: 'pie'
                    },
                    title: {
                        text: 'Jahreszyklus'
                    },
                    yAxis: {
                        title: {
                            text: ''
                        }
                    },
                    plotOptions: {
                        pie: {
                            shadow: false,
                          ignoreHiddenPoint: false,
                          colors: '#ffffff',
                            center: ['50%', '50%'],
                            borderWidth: 0.5,
                            borderColor:null
                        },
                        series: {
                            color: '#ffffff',
                            borderWidth: 0.5,
                            borderColor:"#000000"
                        }
                    },
                    tooltip: {
                        valueSuffix: 'Tage'
                    },
                    series: [{
                        name: 'Monate',
                        data: [
                            {
                                name:'Jan',
                                y:31,
                                color: "#b7e6a1"
                            },
                            {
                                name:'Feb',
                                y:28,
                                color: "#b7e6a1"
                            },
                            {
                                name:'Mar',
                                y:31,
                                color: "#b7e6a1"
                            },
                            {
                                name:'Apr',
                                y:30,
                                color: "#b7e6a1"
                            },
                            {
                                name:'Mai',
                                y:31,
                                color: "#b7e6a1"
                            },
                            {
                                name:'Jun',
                                y:30,
                                color: "#b7e6a1"
                            },
                            {
                                name:'Jul',
                                y:31,
                                color: "#b7e6a1"
                            },
                            {
                                name:'Aug',
                                y:31,
                                color: "#b7e6a1"
                            },
                            {
                                name:'Sep',
                                y:30,
                                color: "#b7e6a1"
                            },
                            {
                                name:'Okt',
                                y:31,
                                color: "#b7e6a1"
                            },
                            {
                                name:'Nov',
                                y:30,
                                color: "#b7e6a1"
                            },
                            {
                                name:'Dec',
                                y:31,
                                color: "#b7e6a1"
                            }
                        ],
                        dataLabels: {distance: -20},
                        enableMouseTracking: false,
                        size: 200,
                        innerSize: 20,
                        borderColor: '#000000'
                    },
                    {
                        name: 'Brut',
                        data: [
                            {
                                name:'',
                                y:151,
                                color: "#ffffff",
                                visible: true
                            },
                            {
                                name:'Brut',
                                y:60,
                                color: "#9afb0d"
                            },
                            {
                                name:'',
                                y:153,
                                color: "#ffffff",
                                visible: true
                            }
                        ],
                        size: 250,
                        innerSize: 201,
                        dataLabels: {distance: -20},
                    },
                    {
                        name: 'BrutRahmen',
                        data: [
                            {
                                name:'',
                                y:365,
                                color: "#ffffff",
                                visible: true
                            }
                        ],
                        size: 251,
                        innerSize: 250,
                        dataLabels: {distance: -15},
                        borderColor: '#000000'
                    },
                    {
                        name: 'Adult',
                        data: [
                            {
                                name:'Adult',
                                y:365,
                                color: "#f9f400",
                                visible: true
                            }
                        ],
                        size: 300,
                        innerSize: 251,
                        dataLabels: {distance: -15},
                    },
                    {
                        name: 'AdultRahmen',
                        data: [
                            {
                                name:'',
                                y:365,
                                color: "#ffffff",
                                visible: true
                            }
                        ],
                        size: 301,
                        innerSize: 300,
                        dataLabels: {distance: -15},
                        borderColor: '#000000'
                    },
                    {
                        name: 'Überwintern',
                        data: [
                            {
                                name:'',
                                y:90,
                                color: "#8ce3e3",
                                visible: true
                            },
                            {
                                name:'',
                                y:214,
                                color: "#ffffff",
                                visible: true
                            },
                            {
                                name:'',
                                y:61,
                                color: "#8ce3e3",
                                visible: true
                            }
                        ],
                        size: 350,
                        innerSize: 301,
                        dataLabels: {distance: -15},
                    },
                    {
                        name: 'ÜberwinternRahmen',
                        data: [
                            {
                                name:'Überwintern',
                                y:365,
                                color: "#ffffff",
                                visible: true
                            }
                        ],
                        size: 351,
                        innerSize: 350,
                        dataLabels: {distance: -16},
                        borderColor: '#000000'
                    },
                    {
                        name: 'Balz und Paarung',
                        data: [
                            {
                                name:'',
                                y:212,
                                color: "#ffffff",
                                visible: true
                            },
                            {
                                name:'',
                                y:61,
                                color: "#48fea7",
                                visible: true
                            },
                            {
                                name:'',
                                y:92,
                                color: "#ffffff",
                                visible: true
                            }
                        ],
                        size: 400,
                        innerSize: 351,
                        dataLabels: {distance: -15},
                    },
                    {
                        name: 'BalzRahmen',
                        data: [
                            {
                                name:'Balz und Paarung',
                                y:365,
                                color: "#ffffff",
                                visible: true
                            }
                        ],
                        size: 401,
                        innerSize: 400,
                        dataLabels: {distance: -20},
                        borderColor: '#000000'
                    }]
                });
            });
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Diagramm</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container" style="height: 500px; width: 500px"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Thanks for any tips!
Best regards
alex

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what do you want to achieve, but as I am looking at the final chart I think that it might be easier to use another series type, I can suggest use:

- radial bar chart: https://www.highcharts.com/demo/polar-radial-bar,
- sunburst: https://www.highcharts.com/demo/sunburst,
- activity gauge: https://www.highcharts.com/demo/gauge-activity